# Beginner's problem - Undefined control sequence

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to produce the following result:

> [/ or ?] - Search for a pattern of text, jump to it by hitting Enter

Then, I tried the following: 
`\item [\/ or \?] - Search for a pattern of text, jump to it by hitting Enter`

But then, I get an "Undefined control sequence."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `\/` nor `\?` are control sequences in LaTeX<sup>*</sup>, causing the error. Instead, you're probably looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item [\texttt{/} or \texttt{?}] - Search for a pattern of text, jump to it by hitting Enter
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The above minimal example typesets `/` and `?` in a monospaced Computer Modern (or typewriter-style) font, within the `description` environment's `\item`. Not sure what exactly your context is, but if you want to include the square brackets `[...]`, use

```
\item [{[\texttt{/} or \texttt{?}]}] ...
```

instead. This puts the contents of the `\item`'s optional argument in a group, rather than confusing TeX in using unmatched brackets and causing spacing problems:

[image]

<sup>*</sup> Well, `\/` is a control sequence (using as an italic correction), but not the one you're after...

Comment: Perfect! That was what I was looking for. Yeah, I'm already using \begin{description}, just was having problems with those characters. Can I use \texttt with any character?

Comment: @Falassion: Some characters are reserved. For example, if you want to use `\ `, you could use `\textbackslash` instead. Others are also reserved, like `^` and `_`, since they're used in math mode. However, there are also text equivalent characters.

Comment: @Falassion: Welcome to TeX.sx! In addition to accepting answers, you can also show that you think an answer is useful by upvoting it by clicking the upward pointing nib next to the answer. Basically, whenever an answer is accepted, it is also upvoted.

Comment: @Werner Interesting, I hadn't cross with \texttt in my Google searches. Just started learning LaTeX, thought. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @Jake Thank you, Jake. I tried upvoting the answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do it yet. But surely I'll come back here and upvote when I do!

Comment: @Falassion: Ah, sorry for that! I wasn't aware of that limitation